# Programmatically add a new field in a template in sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7

In `Sitecore` is it possible to programmatically add a new field in a template?

I have a template "`DictionaryName`", in this template I want to add a field "`Newname`" with its type "`Single-Line Text`".

Comment: This is possible as a template item is like any other item, but this is not something I would recommend doing as your templates are like your database structure and you wouldn't want them dynamically created. If you could elaborate on what your are trying to achieve there might be alternative solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote and tested this code for you - it worked out perfect on my machine and created new single line field within template specified. Here is the method:

```
    private void AddFieldToTemplate(string fieldName, string tempatePath)
    {
        const string templateOftemplateFieldId = "{455A3E98-A627-4B40-8035-E683A0331AC7}";

        // this will do on your "master" database, consider Sitecore.Context.Database if you need "web"
        var templateItem = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master").GetItem(tempatePath);
        if (templateItem != null)
        {
            var templateSection = templateItem.Children.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Template.Name == "Template section");
            if (templateSection != null)
            {
                var newField = templateSection.Add(fieldName, new TemplateID(new ID(templateOftemplateFieldId)));
                using (new EditContext(newField))
                {
                    newField["Type"] = "Text"; // text stands for single-line lext field type
                }
            }
            {
                // there are no template sections here, you may need to create one. template has only inherited fields if any
            }
        }
    }
```

And below is the usage - first string parameter is the name of your new field, the second is string value for template path within the database you are using:

```
AddFieldToTemplate("New Single Line Field", "/sitecore/templates/Sample/Sample Item");
```

Replace "Sample Item" template with your template path and set desired field name to add. Also do not forget usings for namespaces:

```
using Sitecore;
using Sitecore.Data;
using Sitecore.Data.Items;
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You can access programmatically a template from the item and then add a an item to this template. The template is a usual item childrens.

Answer (score 0):

**Wrote this Example for you.**

> Want to find out more https://doc.sitecore.com/legacy-docs/SC71/data-definition-api-cookbook-sc70-a4.pdf

```
public JsonResult CreateTemplate()
    {
        try
        {
            using(new SecurityDisabler())
            {
                ///Get Database
                Database master = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master");

                /// Every node in content tree ia an Item. Ex- Templates,Field, Item, etc.
                /// Template: /sitecore/templates/System/Templates/Template -{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}
                var templateId = master.GetTemplate(new ID("{AB86861A-6030-46C5-B394-E8F99E8B87DB}"));

               /// parentItem is the item/ Template folder where you want to create your template.
               /// ParentItem: /sitecore/templates/[new folder {Guid}]
                Item parentItem = master.GetItem(new ID("{3C7516ED-7E3E-4442-8124-26691599596E}"));


                Item newItem = parentItem.Add("HelloTemplate", templateId);

                // adding Field in Templates.
                TemplateItem exampleTemplate = master.Templates[new ID(newItem.ID.ToString())];

                TemplateSectionItem data = exampleTemplate?.GetSection("data");

                if( data == null || data.InnerItem.Parent.ID != exampleTemplate.ID)
                {
                    data = exampleTemplate.AddSection("Data", false);
                }
                TemplateFieldItem title = data?.GetField("title");
                if(title == null)
                {
                    TemplateFieldItem field = data.AddField("Title");
                }
            }
                return Json(new { Result = "item created" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
            
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = "item not created " + ex.Message+"\n"+ex.StackTrace } , JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```